# Problem with Space in Variable on Batch-Script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a problem with my batch script.
I want to delete a file witch I first copy in an variable.
If I output the variable all spaces are there.
but if I try to delete it, the filename stops at the first space.

```
For /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /B *.mkv') do set orginaldatei=%%~ni.mkv
ECHO %orginaldatei%
del %orginaldatei%
```

I also tried it without the "delims=".

Comment: Use quotes to protect against spaces: `del "%originaldatei%"`. Actually, `del hello world` tries to delete the file `hello` and the file `world` (even documented with `dir /?`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to quote the filename.

```
del "%orginaldatei%"
```

That's because `del` accepts a list of files to delete, delimited by spaces.
Quotes help to make clear, if a space is a delimiter or part of a filename.

```
del my file     --- Tries to delete "my" and "file"
del "my file"   --- Tries to delete "my file"
```